# How to find a consistent hash of a tarball

Tags: python, hash, tar

How do you create a tarball so that its md5 or sha512 hash will be deterministic?

I'm currently creating a tarball of a directory of source code files by running `tar --exclude-vcs --create --verbose --dereference --gzip --file mycode.tgz *`, and I'd like to record its hash so I can use it as a fingerprint for detecting changes in the future.

However, I've noticed that if I create duplicate tarballs without changing any files, running the Python `hashlib.sha512(open('mycode.tgz').read()).hexdigest()` on each archive returns a different hash.

Is this because tar's compression algorithm is not deterministic? If so, how can I efficiently archive a large collection of files in such a way that I can calculate a consistent hash to detect changes?

Comment: `tar` doesn't have a compression algorithm - it's the `--gzip` option that applies gzip compression to the tarball. Would be interesting to know whether the problem persists without `--gzip` (and switching then to a plain `.tar` extension). Then at least you'd find out whether the differences are coming from `tar` or from `gzip`.

Comment: As I said below, tar includes a modification date in its header, so it's likely at least caused by that.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably possible to generate a version of tar that produces deterministic hashes, but rather than doing that, most packaging systems that need tar hashes consistent use something like [pristine-tar](http://kitenet.net/~joey/code/pristine-tar/).  Unfortunately, pristine-tar will not help for your use case.

However, the Git version control system is quite good at generating consistent hashs (sha-1 not sha-512) of a directory tree though.

```
git add .
git write-tree
```

will print a hash that is consistent except when something changes.
File contents and mode changes will be tracked.

Comment: +1, though I believe tar files include a modification date in their headers, (at least according to wikipedia), so it seems like it would be awkward to generate a consistent tar file.

Comment: @JesseRusak Yeah, I was thinking of a custom tar program that among other things chose most recent file time as header mod time.  Possible but way too difficult for practicality

Answer (score 1):

After finding [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/213129/how-to-get-100-identical-compressed-files-for-source-files-that-only-differ-in), I realized that my archives are actually nearly identical, except for the first few bytes that contain a timestamp. Changing my code to `hashlib.sha512(open(fn).read()[8:]).hexdigest()` to strip off the first few characters fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Gnu tar can set the timestamps for consistent hashing.

```
tar --sort=name --owner=root:0 --group=root:0 --mtime='UTC 2019-01-01' ...
```

Credits: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54908072

Answer (score 0):

The shell glob might be shuffling the order of the files as they're added to the archive. Maybe try specifying the exact order with something like:

```
find . | sort | tar -T - --exclude-vcs --create --verbose --dereference --gzip --file mycode.tgz
```

Comment: Shell globbing doesn't shuffle the filenames, it expands to a sorted list, albeit that's depending on the active locale.

Comment: @user2719058 Good point. Perhaps tar, seeing only the top-level directories, is picking lower-level files/directories in a non-deterministic order. Or maybe I'm completely off the mark.