# How to create a tar file that omits timestamps for its contents?

Tags: build, timestamp, archive, tar

Is there a way to create a `.tar` file that omits the values of atime/ctime/mtime for its files/directories?

## Why do we want to do this?

We have a step in our build process that generates a directory of artifacts that gets packaged into a tarfile.  We expect that build step to be idempotent -- given the same inputs, it produces *exactly* the same files/output each time.

Ideally, we would like also like the step to be *bitwise* idempotent across clean builds, so that we can use hashes of successive builds to check that nothing has changed.  But because tar files include timestamps (atime/ctime/mtime) for each entry, the tar files created by that build step are never bitwise identical to the previous run, even though the contents of every file inside the archive *are* bitwise identical.

Is there a way to generate a tarfile that omits the timestamps of its entries, so that the step that generates the archive *could* be bitwise idempotent?  (We want to leverage other file metadata that `tar` preserves, such as file mode bits and symlinks.)

Comment: did you ever find a complete answer to this?  I also want to do the same thing, asked in a question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45734702/tar-preserving-only-file-names-contents-and-executable-bit?noredirect=1#comment78427625_45734702  I also want to make sure the user, group and permissions are not stored.  Is there anything else to be aware of?

Comment: @TomEllis, I would consider building something custom with the Python `tarfile` module if you want exact control of which permissions are and aren't stored.

Comment: Have a look at this: https://reproducible-builds.org/docs/archives/#full-example

Answer (score 39, accepted):

To have a truly idempotent tar, `mtime` is a good step but not enough.
You also need to set the sort order, the owner and group (together with their mapping) and a proper timezone for `mtime` (since otherwise you're gonna have issues as well between Mac and Linux).

I ended up with

```sh
tar --sort=name --owner=root:0 --group=root:0 --mtime='UTC 2019-01-01' ... | gzip -n
```

Comment: Note: this solution requires GNU tar 1.28 or higher.

Comment: Do you also need to enforce a well-defined sort order, perhaps by setting the env variable `LC_ALL=c`?

Comment: @Mickalot, you **explicitly** said in the question: *We want to leverage other file metadata that tar preserves*, asking answers to limit themselves to only discussing timestamps. Shifting the acceptance bit to an answer that isn't honoring that specification strikes me as moving the goalposts.

Comment: The question asked about bitwise idempotency so I think it is appropriate for answers to include anything contributing to that goal, including file ownership and sort order.

Comment: @Mickalot then do you really want tar then ? If you don't want meta data then you might consider reading this thread https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/349948 or give @ Charles Duffy the accepted answer

Comment: @Et7f3XIV: Charles Duffy's answer is a wonderful response to what I literally asked.  This answer improves upon my question and (correctly) surmises what I should have asked.  They're both great answers, and I wish I had two "accepted answers" to hand out.

Answer (score 28):

GNU tar has a `--mtime` argument, which can be used to store a fixed date in the archive rather than a file's actual mtime:

```
tar --mtime='1970-01-01' input ...
```

When compressing a tarball with gzip, it's also necessary to specify `-n` to prevent name and timestamp of the tar archive from being stored:

```
tar --mtime='1970-01-01' input ... | gzip -n >input.tar.gz
```

Comment: How can this be done in macOS? I cannot find `--mtime`

Comment: @mljrg : the standard tar on macOS is bsd based, and BSD tar is different from GNU tar.  To install GNU tar, if you use homebrew, you can `brew install gnu-tar` which makes the GNU tar available as `gtar`.

Comment: @Mickalot Thanks!

Comment: `--mtime='@0'` is shorter and appears to function the same (tarballs made using both options matched MD5sums).

Answer (score 2):

## Many options required

Reproducible-builds.org has a long explainer online for the tar archive format(s).

They arrive at this:

> ## Full example
>
> The recommended way to create a Tar archive is thus:
>
> ```bash
> # requires GNU Tar 1.28+
> $ tar --sort=name \
>      --mtime="@${SOURCE_DATE_EPOCH}" \
>      --owner=0 --group=0 --numeric-owner \
>      --pax-option=exthdr.name=%d/PaxHeaders/%f,delete=atime,delete=ctime \
>      -cf product.tar build
> ```

But I suggest you run it without the `${SOURCE_DATE_EPOCH}` variable (and instead use literal "@0"):

```bash
# requires GNU Tar 1.28+
$ tar --sort=name \
     --mtime="@0" \
     --owner=0 --group=0 --numeric-owner \
     --pax-option=exthdr.name=%d/PaxHeaders/%f,delete=atime,delete=ctime \
     -cf product.tar build
```

Read the full explainer here: https://reproducible-builds.org/docs/archives/

Comment: This is the only answer that deals with atime and ctime. A quick test reveals that that's absolutely necessary to make it reproducible.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone wants to create reproducible hashes of the directory, I improved a bit answer of @StackzOfZtuff and added deleting the second half of timestamps (btime, mtime):

```bash
tar \
  --sort=name \
  --mtime="@0" \
  --owner=0 \
  --group=0 \
  --numeric-owner \
  --pax-option=exthdr.name=%d/PaxHeaders/%f,delete=atime,delete=ctime,delete=btime,delete=mtime \
  -cf - -C yourDirectoryPath . | sha256sum | head -c 64
```

Plus if you want to debug why two tar archives are different even if were created from the directories with the same content, you can pass archives through `| strings` that will give them more human readable look and then pass through diff.

```bash
git diff --color=always <(
  tar ...params -cf - -C dir1 . | strings
) <(
  tar ...params -cf - -C dir2 . | strings
)
```

[image]