# tar: preserving only file names, contents and executable bit

Tags: tar, gnu-coreutils

I want to use `tar` to preserve *only* file names, file contents, and the executable bit for the owner (and ignore the executable bit for group and other).  The command I have come up with is

```
tar -cf <name>.tar --numeric-owner --owner=0 --group=0 --mode="go-rwx,u-rw" <files>
```

I would like the output `<name>.tar` not to change unless I change the file name, file contents, or owner's executable bit in one or more of `<files>`.    Assume that the `<files>` are in sorted order by name.

Will the command that I have written do that?

Comment: What exactly does not work with the command that you have given?

Comment: The command works fine.  I'm wondering whether it always creates the exact same file when the input filenames, file contents, and owner execute bit are the same.

Comment: Have you tried to make some changes to the files, and then comparing the checksums of the reslting tar file?

Comment: I know that if I change the file the output will change!  I asking whether there are *other* things I can change that will cause the output to change.  One such thing that I now realise that I left off is the `mtime`.  I'm asking if there are others.

Comment: OK, I see. I would recommend to explicitly state that in your initial question.

Comment: Which bit of my question should I change?  I hoped I had made it clear.

Comment: @TomEllis Have you managed to find the solution? Also, do you know how to do in the reverse direction, that is, given any tar archive, how do you extract only the file name, contents and executable bit, for every entry in the archive?

Comment: @mljrg I wrote up a complete summary of my findings here http://h2.jaguarpaw.co.uk/posts/reproducible-tar/ It answers the Y that this question was an X to, about reproducibility.  I hope that helps you.

Comment: @TomEllis Maybe you will find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46321878/how-to-verify-if-the-content-of-two-docker-images-is-exactly-the-same) interesting and useful.